# How to unpublish social media icons from a single article in joomla 3?

Tags: joomla3.0

It's a simple form and does not need social sharing. How to remove social media icons from an article in joomla3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla 3 does not have and social media sharing functionality. If your site does then it is provided by a 3rd party extension, not Joomla, and without some information from you it is impossible for anyone to know what that might be.

Update: Thanks for sharing a link. The social sharing functions are part of your Gavick template, the so-called Gavick Social API, so I'd advise you to check out their documention (https://www.gavick.com/documentation/joomla/gavern-framework/social-api-2)  and/or support forum.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am using K2. But it's not a K2 page. It's a Joomla article. Here is the link. http://yankeerussia.com/index.php/component/content/article?id=18 
Social icons are at the bottom of the page.

Comment: So it's the template. How did you find it was a Gavick template? Just curious.